# On homophonic tuples of words with slight differences in meaning

Tags: homophonic-kanji, homonyms

I am wondering if tuples of words such as:

- 聞く、聴く、訊く
- 効く、利く
- 硬い、固い、堅い

which are homophones with only a very nuanced difference in meaning, have a name and whether or not they've been studied by linguists. (I am particularly curious about the emergence of such tuples and why it doesn't seem like each tuple will merge into one single word any time soon.)

Comment: I believe if it weren't for the borrowed writing system of kanji, the first five would be considered various meanings of one same word. The last three are still listed as one word in dictionaries. So the phenomenon you are curious about seems specific to languages that have experienced later assignment of imported ideograms onto native words.